# Get all API fields definitions from Podio application

Tags: api, field, definition, podio

Responses from Podio API returns an JSON array of items with a `fields` property. Each field carries its `values` and its `config`.

For example a *category* field for the *Gender*:

```
{
        "type": "category",
        "field_id": 219922852,
        "label": "Gender",
        "values": [
          {
            "value": {
              "status": "active",
              "text": "Prefer not to say",
              "id": 3,
              "color": "F7F0C5"
            }
          }
        ],
        "config": {
          "settings": {
            "multiple": true,
            "options": [
              {
                "status": "active",
                "text": "Male",
                "id": 1,
                "color": "DCEBD8"
              },
              {
                "status": "active",
                "text": "Female",
                "id": 2,
                "color": "F7F0C5"
              },
              {
                "status": "active",
                "text": "Prefer not to say",
                "id": 3,
                "color": "F7F0C5"
              }
            ],
            "display": "inline"
          },
          "mapping": null,
          "label": "Gender"
        },
        "external_id": "gender"
      },
```

---

1. How can I fetch the `config` without having to query a specific item?
2. Is there a way to get **every field** in the response? Because if the queried item does not have a field value set, Podio doesn't return it in the response.
3. I would like to get **the field config for ALL the fields**. If possible, with a single API request. In particular I am interested in **all the possible values** (in case of Category or Relationship fields) so that I could match them with local values I have.

This way I can use the field structure to programmatically map some local values to the format required by the Podio API; and then generate a `fields` payload that to update/create Podio items via an API calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can request the `Podio Get App` method to get the app configuration.

Podio Doc Ref: https://developers.podio.com/doc/applications/get-app-22349

Comment: Thank you, that answers part of the question. I edited to emphasize the last part: do you know how to include in the response also *"all the possible values"* for the field of `app` type? Or do I need an additional API request (one for each Relationship field) in order to fetch all the possible values/itemIds?

Comment: Each field's config settings will tell you which apps it can reference. You would then need to use /item/app/{app_id}/filter/ to get the items from each of those apps.